# A single word for people who believe that they belong together in this and other lives

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe people who say or promise to their loved ones to be each other's forever, and that every time they come to earth or are born they will be each other's.

So what is it called to be someone's even after death; each time you are born you would like to become theirs.

I want a word that literally means to become someone's each time you come into the world or are reborn.

Comment: I think that's what the terminally love-struck refer to as a *soulmate* or a `kindred soul`

Comment: Thanks for your answer and Yes! Soulmate is a nice word but it doesn't convey for what I am looking. I mean a literal word that means to become someone's after every birth. Soulmate is like when souls are tied like nothing can separate you, but it doesn't mean the way I want it.

Comment: I am unable to conceive of a single word, but remain, "eternally yours"

Comment: Hi, Ehaan :-). It would be easier for people who are trying to answer your question if you included the words that **don't** work for you in your question and explained why (so that they don't waste time on something that wouldn't help you). Also, in the future it is better to give your questions a specific title - your tags already say that you want a single word for something, but saying what exactly in the title also helps those who are trying to answer. I did this for you once, and I tried to do it here (if my suggestion survives high-rep user's revision :-)).

Comment: You're such a romantic, @ermanen.

Comment: @LittleEva: Being realistic :)

Comment: Most of the English-speaking world does not believe in reincarnation. You will probably need to find a speaker of Indian English to come up with such a word.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a *duprass*, which is a specific type of *karass*, as defined by the great philosopher, Kurt Vonnegut.

> karass - A group of people linked in a cosmically significant manner, even when superficial linkages are not evident.
>
> duprass - a karass of only two people, who almost always die within a week of each other. The typical example is a loving couple who work together for a great purpose.

A fuller discussion is found in his seminal religious tome, *[Cat's Cradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat's_Cradle)* (as summarized in the ultimate reference work, *Wikipedia*).

Comment: It says that the words are unique to the novel and the definition doesn't fit.

Comment: @ermanen Dr. Vonnegut (he got an honorary PhD somewhere) has cast them out into the ether, and if we incorporate them into our speech and lives, do we not honor the Master? As to definitions, all we have to do is incorporate reincarnation into the mix and insist that the cosmic significance is so great that it must go on forever. Is that so hard?

Comment: Still no satisfactory answer :(